# Looking for Ubuntu linux driver for NIKON coolpix 100 pcmcia camera

Tags: camera

Got this NIKON CoolPix 100 camera that plugs into the laptop PCMCIA slot to download photos, but when I plug it in, it isn't recognized, and the CD for it has no Linux drivers.

Any ideas on how I can use my camera in Linux?

Comment: Why would you need a driver?! You need a connection protocol (like mtp, PTP (<-- it is probably that one you need) or PictBridge) not a driver. http://gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php has it listed as supported. "into the laptop PCMCIA slot" Sorry? Use the USB slot on the PC. PCMCIA is not for connecting.

Comment: the camera has no usb or other connection but the pcmcia card - the battery pack slips off to reveal the pcmcia card, which when plugged into the pcmcia slot in my windows machines, sees it as a drive with files... the camera manual says something about RAM card driver which supports ATA interface...

Comment: No, That's not what I said: you connect the camera to the PC using the usb on the PC and not the PCMCIA slot. Assuming your camera connects over PTP ( that is a setting in the camera. See http://ptp.sourceforge.net/ for more on PTP )  then GPhoto http://www.gphoto.org/ will do the data transfers.

Comment: sorry - the camera has only the pcmcia - no usb connection on it :-\
(the pcmcia is built into the camera and is the only interface - battery part slips over the pcmcia and ends up plugging into the top of the camera for taking photos...)
... unless I find a pcmcia female to usb male adapter... usb's did not exist when this digital camera was made~

Comment: That is not what I said. Please read what I commented on. I never claimed your camera has usb. I said you need to use the USB on the PC and not the PCMCIA on your PC (as you say in your question). The protocol to connect to your camera is PTP and you need to set it on your camera. When that is done software like gphoto can fetch and store content.

Comment: I have a pcmcia slot on my computer, when I plug the one and only connection possible from the camera to ANY computer which is the camera's built-in pcmcia card, the camera's LCD displays "PC", but the Ubuntu 17.04 Panasonic laptop does not indicate it as a drive like it does with MSDOS, Windows 3.1, Windows 98... so their file manager can access the photo files - there is no 'setting' on this camera for PTP, only image quality and flash on/off. How would I 'use' my PC's usb to 'access' a camera with no removable storage- only a single PC connection => PCMCIA?

Comment: OK - seems it is 'Card Services' that needs installing to get the computer's pcmcia slot to read the camera's pcmcia connection, but after getting as far as putting the 'pcmcia-cs-3.2.8' directory into '/usr/src/', then getting stuck with questions running 'make config' that I can't fathom any correct answers for... I'll just have to stick with using my Compaq Armada running Windows 98 (1st edition) pcmcia slot to read/edit/etc my photos ~ just another 'thing' on this ubuntu laptop (of a long list of things so far) that'll just never work right... too bad sudo apt-get install pcmcia-cs is dead

Comment: pcmcia-cs is would not install as it is for older kernels... seems pcmcia support is supposedly built-in to newer kernels - got the following info:

$ lspcmcia
Socket 0 Bridge:       [yenta_cardbus]     (bus ID: 0000:06:01.0)
Socket 0 Device 0:    [pata_pcmcia]        (bus ID: 0.0)

$ dpkg-query -l pcmcia* | grep ii
ii  pcmciautils    018-8        i386         PCMCIA utilities for Linux 2.6

$ apropos pcmcia
lspcmcia (8)         - display extended PCMCIA debugging information
pccardctl (8)        - PCMCIA card control utility

Comment: Got this, but the FAT is fine....
$ dmesg | tail
[  102.529320] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[  721.175328] perf: interrupt took too long (2507 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[ 2262.800046] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: pccard: PCMCIA card inserted into slot 0
[ 2262.800058] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xb8010000-0xb80fffff:
[ 2262.812396]  excluding 0xb80fe000-0xb810bfff

Comment: ...and the rest:
[ 2262.812768] pcmcia 0.0: pcmcia: registering new device pcmcia0.0 (IRQ: 3)
[ 2263.261914] scsi host2: pata_pcmcia
[ 2263.262155] ata3: PATA max PIO0 cmd 0x4100 ctl 0x410e irq 3
[ 2263.544888] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (device reports invalid type, err_mask=0x0)
[ 2268.924911] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (device reports invalid type, err_mask=0x0)

Comment: off topic for the camera part, but more on the pcmcia part...
I get the following after I plug-in my 56k baud US Robotics PCMCIA modem:
$ dmesg | tail
[ 135.820060] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xb8010000-0xb80fffff:
[ 135.833372] excluding 0xb80fe000-0xb810bfff
[ 135.833759] pcmcia 0.0: pcmcia: registering new device pcmcia0.0 (IRQ: 3)
[ 135.925602] serial_cs 0.0: trying to set up [0x0102:0x002f] (pfc: 0, multi: 1, quirk: (null))
[ 135.998420] 0.0: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[ 238.165601] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0:

Comment: ...and the rest, again:pccard: card ejected from slot 0
[ 298.796070] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: pccard: PCMCIA card inserted into slot 0
[ 298.796459] pcmcia 0.0: pcmcia: registering new device pcmcia0.0 (IRQ: 3)
[ 298.798559] serial_cs 0.0: trying to set up [0x0102:0x002f] (pfc: 0, multi: 1, quirk: (null))
[ 298.934759] 0.0: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A

...but alas, there is only 'ethernet' and wifi' options in my network selections - no 'modem', or 'dial-up', or anything else...